# ASP.net core + Angular Fallback route excluding subpaths starting with /api

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

When using the ASP.net core Angular 2 template the routes are setup to fallback to the angular app if a route can't be found

```
            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
                );
```

This is fine except that it also catches invalid api routes. How can you add a constraint so it will not fallback to routes starting with **/api**

Answer (score 0):

According to my reserach it can be accomplished with two methods:

**Method one (using middleware):**

read [Rick Stahl's blog article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2020/Jul/12/Handling-SPA-Fallback-Paths-in-a-Generic-ASPNET-Core-Server)

I generally don't like this middleware handling because it puts one more level of complexity to your routing.

**Method two (using conventional routing):**

Put apiFallback route to Startup.cs like this

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers(); // here you have your api controllers with whatever routing you use (conventional or using attributes)

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    // this is your API fallback route for handling every previously unhandled route starting with api/ and send everything past api as an endpointName parameter
    // remember to put this route to nearly bottom of UseEndpoints method as it's very greedy
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "apiFallback",
        pattern: "api/{*endpointName}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ApiNotFoundFallback" });

    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); // here is your SPA page
});
```

Now let's create ApiNotFoundFallback controller action in your Home controller (or wherever else you desire - don't forget to change the defaults in apiFallback route accordingly then)

```
public IActionResult ApiNotFoundFallback(string endpointName)
{
    return NotFound($"No endpoint matching \"{endpointName}\" not found!");
}
```

And voila! All routes not starting by /api and not handled by your controllers falls to index.html and all API "not founds" are handled by ApiNotFoundFallback action.